# Is it possible requery a form open with Docmd.openform "nameform",,,,acformAdd?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm facing with a form and I need to know if possible to use - Me.requery- method on a Form that i've opened with
**Docmd.openform "nameform",acNormal,,,acformAdd.**

In other words my Dbase have Form_A and table_A. I can scroll and edit records using Form A.
When I need to insert a new record I use the method :

***DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_A", acNormal, , , acFormAdd***
*emphasized text**emphasized text*
and insert the new record.
The question is:
How can I scroll all recordset without close and reopen the form? is't possible requery the form_A directly .
Many thanks to all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You open the form to add records only:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_A", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
```

Don't do that:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form_A"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a workaround :

```
    Private Sub cmdnewprogetto_Click()

    Application.Echo False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_A", acNormal
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Frm_A", acNewRec
    Application.Echo True

    End sub
```